# IntelliJ unresolved function or method with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellij-idea

I've been fighting with `$` being marked as `unresolved function or method` when IntelliJ is doing it's analysis. I tried [downloading the jQuery library](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-javascript-libraries.html) as part of IntelliJ and set the scope to global, but it still doesn't work. I'm currently using jquery 12.1.6.

Is there a way to get IntelliJ to realize that the $ is defined globally?

Comment: @Bala555, answers go down there.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery v1.11.0 shows exactly the same behaviour here as well. At the same time previous version 1.10.2 works fine in IDE (no warnings).

I think it has something to do with "AMD-fy jQuery source" ticket (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14113) -- looks like IDE has some issues figuring out this style.

If you wish (and can) -- roll back to jQuery v1.10.2 (which is like half a year old, which means it's stable and still good to use).

Hopefully IDE will be able to properly parse this new jQuery style in next release.

Actual ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10908